# Trees/tableaux fir K-IF logic

Tags: logic, formalisation

Are there any attempts for tableaux/ tree rules for Hintikkas [K](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-epistemic/)-[IF](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-if/) logic?

Comment: I do not think so; see Gabriel Sandu & Merlijn Sevenster & Allen Mann, [Independence-Friendly Logic : A Game-Theoretic Approach](https://books.google.it/books?id=_ULc89HndUAC&pg=PA128), Cambridge UP (2011), page 128.

Comment: For some reason I can't read page 128, would you be so kind to quote the relevant passage?